# How does TensorFlow differentiate the training step from the inference?

Tags: tensorflow

Could you please tell me how TensorFlow differentiates the training step from the inference? In most examples I found, they use the same call for both steps.

Comment: Both training and validation can be done using TF's session.run(). It depends what do you assign as inputs and outputs to this function call.

Comment: Could you please give me an example or detail more what could be the difference between the inputs and outputs of each step?

Comment: Check this example : https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.py

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 1.x, you need to define a Session and both training and prediction happens inside it. But if you look carefully you will find inputs to `sess.run()` are different, when training the `feed_dict` contains both x and corresponding y's. Like:

```
loss, _ = sess.run([loss_op, any_other_parameter_you_want], feed_dict={X: batch_x,Y: batch_y})
```

And for prediction the `feed_dict` will contain only `x` values, also you will specify the parameter `y_out` (the output of your model):

```
out = sess.run(y_out, feed_dict={X: batch_x})
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i got this error message : You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [2,3,4]
  [[{{node Placeholder_1}}]]